# Creating Join table with multiple Primary Keys?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, join

I have a problem creating a Join Table with multiple primary keys. Below is my table structure:

[image: Table Structure]

Below is my JPA implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "label")
public class Label {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenant_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "label_id")
    private String label_id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Report.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "tagging", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"))
    private Set<Report> reports;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenant_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "report_id")
    private String report_id;

    @column(name = "created_by")
    private String created_by;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Label.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "tagging", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"))
    private Set<Label> labels;

}
```

This works fine, but when I try to add in `tenant_id` into the mix like so:

Label.java edit:

```
@JoinTable(name = "tagging", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"), inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id") })
private Set<Report> reports;
```

Report.java edit:

```
@JoinTable(name = "tagging", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"), inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id") })
private Set<Label> labels;
```

I get an error saying that `“A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 1”`. As far as I understand, this is because I only have one primary key named Report and label each so I cannot map the `tenant_id` as a `JoinColumn`. However, I was wondering, is there any way to set the `tenant_id` when the `report_id` and `label_id` are set also? Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT: The @Id fields in the entities are tenant_id and id in both the Report and Label classes.

Comment: What are your foreign keys? Just so I can try to scribe a mapping for you

Comment: @Desorder I actually don't have foreign keys. My tables don't have any foreign keys.

Comment: why is tenant_id not part of the PK in the other 2 tables? why are there 2 columns in the join table that are string yet you have int in the other 2 tables? Fix the tables first

Comment: @NeilStockton I apologize, I did it in a hurry. I have fixed it now.

Comment: ok, and now what are the @Id fields in the entities? They have to have some identity field(s) that correspond to the PK columns in the tables.

Comment: The `@Id` fields in the entities are tenant_id and id in both the Report and Label classes.

@NeilStockton

Comment: Well firstly your column mappings are wrong ("label_id" in class, "id" in table), they are inconsistent with your schema. Secondly your joinColumns are wrong since they ignore the "tenant_id" column.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not able to try this out but from the top of my head, it's something like this. There are a few things to fix like the complete annotation properties as the column names and class members are not the same but that is the idea. :)

more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm)

**Report class**

```
@Entity
public class Report {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String createdBy;

    @Column
    private String tenantId;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Tagging> taggings = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter and setters

}
```

**Label class**

```
@Entity
public class Label {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String tenantId;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Tagging> taggings = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter and setters

}
```

**Tagging class**

```
@Entity
public class Tagging {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TaggingId id;

    @OneToMany
    private Report report;

    @OneToMany
    private Label label;

    // getter and setters

}

@Embeddable
class TaggingId {

    private Integer reportId;

    private String labelId;

    private String tenantId;

    // getter and setters

}
```